# Getting the request parameters inside page fragments, loaded with jQuery load()?

Tags: jquery, parameters, request, page-fragments

I have a web-application with a main menu, which loads all pages inside a div, located in my main.html. I load the pages with jQuery `.load()` like this:

```
$(".main-content-container").load("view-user.html?id=123 .sub-content-container");
```

I would like inside the loaded page fragment (`view-user.html`) to be able to get the request parameters (`id=123` in this case) in order to be able to fill the form with the data for the user with the given ID. If I use `window.location.href` though I receive not `view-user.html?id=123`, but `main.html` instead, which is expected actually, since that is what is shown all the time in browser's address bar. So, the question is: is there a way to obtain the request parameters inside the page fragment when loading it?

Comment: Made it to work using sessionStorage object, but any better idea would be appreciated, as well as any downsides of my current approach.